# Cayley’s Theorem Isomorphic Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

$5$. Consider the set $G = (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15)$

(a) Show that this set is closed under the binary operation
x, y → xy (mod 16)

and write down the corresponding multiplication table. [8]

(b) Show that G is a group under this operation and find all its cyclic subgroups. [6]

(c) Is G isomorphic to Z8? Justify your answer. [6]

(d) State Cayley’s theorem and find a subgroup in S8 which is isomorphic to G...

I have completed parts a, b and c but d is giving me some trouble.

I can see that the subgroup will be (3,9,11,1) based on my answer to part c, but how that justifies 10 marks in part d is beyond me. I'm not sure where the problem lies.

Cayley's Theorem: Any finite group of order n is isomorphic to a subgroup of symmetric group $S_n$

In looking at the Cayley's theorem proof, I cant find the way to apply it to my specific problem, so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: What subgroup will be $(3,9,11,1)$? That is not a subgroup in the first place.

Comment: You need a subgroup of $\;S_8\;$ isomorphic with your $\;G\;$ , thus: you need a subgroup of order $\;8\;$ in $\;S_8\;$ ....and you need it abelian but non-cyclic ( based on what answers had to be to part of questions $\;a-b-c\;$)

Comment: Something is not quite right regarding your interpretation of (d). S8 denotes the permutation group on 8 symbols, which has order $8!$, and your job is to find a subgroup of that permutation group (which is isomorphic to $G$).

Comment: If it's isomorphic to $G$, it's got to have exactly eight elements, so I'm not sure what your current 'subgroup' is useful for. Try considering the orders of the elements in $G$, and what permissions these would correspond to.

Comment: BTW, did you already classify the abelian group $\;G\;$ ? That might help...

Comment: It is standard to use curly brackets, $\{$ and $\}$, as delimiters for sets, rather than parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

As for d), you have got to literally stuck to what the theorem states, namely:
$$G\stackrel{\varphi}{\cong} K :=\{1\cdot\_\space,3\cdot\_\space,5\cdot\_\space,7\cdot\_\space,9\cdot\_\space,11\cdot\_\space,13\cdot\_\space,15\cdot\_\space\}\le S_G \tag1$$
where, for all $i\in G$, "$i\cdot\_$" is the bijection on $G$ defined by $j\mapsto i\cdot j\pmod{16}$.

And $K$ can be "isomorphically transferred" into $S_8$ via $\psi_f\colon S_G \to S_8$, defined by $\sigma\mapsto f\sigma f^{-1}$ for *any* bijection $f\colon G\to\{1,\dots,8\}$. For example, the choice:
$$f(1_G)=1,\space f(3_G)=2,\space f(5_G)=3,\space f(7_G)=4,\space f(9_G)=5,\space f(11_G)=6,\space f(13_G)=7,\space f(15_G)=8$$
yields:
\begin{alignat}{1}
(\psi_f(1_G\cdot\_))(1) &= (f(1_G\cdot\_) f^{-1})(1) \\
&= f((1_G\cdot\_)(f^{-1}(1))) \\
&= f(1_G\cdot 1_G\pmod{16}) \\
&= f(1_G) \\
&= 1
\end{alignat}
\begin{alignat}{1}
(\psi_f(1_G\cdot\_))(2) &= (f(1_G\cdot\_) f^{-1})(2) \\
&= f((1_G\cdot\_)(f^{-1}(2))) \\
&= f(1_G\cdot 3_G\pmod{16}) \\
&= f(3_G) \\
&= 2
\end{alignat}
\begin{alignat}{1}
(\psi_f(1_G\cdot\_))(3) &= (f(1_G\cdot\_) f^{-1})(3) \\
&= f((1_G\cdot\_)(f^{-1}(3))) \\
&= f(1_G\cdot 5_G\pmod{16}) \\
&= f(5_G) \\
&= 3
\end{alignat}
*etc.*. So, finally:
$$\psi_f(1_G\cdot\_)=()$$
Likewise, you will find:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&\psi_f(3_G\cdot\_) &&=(1256)(3874) \\
&\psi_f(5_G\cdot\_) &&=(1357)(2864) \\
&\psi_f(7_G\cdot\_) &&=(14)(23)(58)(67) \\
&\psi_f(9_G\cdot\_) &&=(15)(26)(37)(48) \\
&\psi_f(11_G\cdot\_) &&=(1652)(3478) \\
&\psi_f(13_G\cdot\_) &&=(1753)(2468) \\
&\psi_f(15_G\cdot\_) &&=(18)(27)(36)(45) \\
\end{alignat}
whence: $$G\stackrel{\psi_f\varphi}{\cong}\{(),(1256)(3874),(1357)(2864),(14)(23)(58)(67),(15)(26)(37)(48),(1652)(3478),(1753)(2468),(18)(27)(36)(45)\}\le S_8$$ (so, incidentally,
$G\cong C_2\times C_4$). It may worth noting that $G\hookrightarrow S_8$ non-canonically ("$f$").